# How to choose output file name when compiling via command line

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm using Linux and I have a project that I have to compile for Windows x86 and x64, I'm successfully using the following commands:

x86:

```
cargo build --release --lib --target i686-pc-windows-gnu
```

output name:

```
my_project.dll
```

x64

```
cargo build --release --lib --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
```

output name:

```
my_project.dll
```

What I want is to put the name in the output file referring to the architecture on x86, example:

```
my_project_x86.dll
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by updating your `Cargo.toml` file and add this section

```
[[bin]]
name = "new name"
path = "path to the main.rs or lib.rs"
```

ref
https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1706
https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#binaries

Comment: but in this case the output files still have the same names, right?